# Workbook isn't Showing when is opened from Form

Tags: vba, forms, excel

I have two Workbooks. The Workbook1  run and display the Userform1 which at the same time hide the workbook1 with this Sub procedure:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Application.Visible = True
    MainForm.Hide
    On Error Resume Next
End Sub
```

But I also have the need to open the Workbook2  from the userform1 using a Command Button with the following Code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

        Dim Finfo As String
        Dim FilterIndex As Integer
        Dim Title As String
        Dim Filename As Variant
        Dim wb As Workbook


'      Setup the list of file filters

        Finfo = "Excel Files (*.xlsx),*xlsx,"

'      Display *.* by default

        FilterIndex = 1*

'       Set the dialog box caption

        Title = "Select a File to Open"

    '   Get the Filename
        Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Finfo, _
        FilterIndex, Title)

'       Handle return info from dialog box

        If Filename = False Then
        MsgBox "No file was selected."
        Else
        MsgBox "You selected " & Filename
        End If

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename)

        End Sub
```

My problem is that  since the part or the code for the commandbutton2 has the part of the code Application.Visible = False  when I Opened the Workbook2 I'm not able to see it unless I close the userform1. So I would like to keep the Workbook1 Hide while I'm Able to see and work the Workbook2. Thank you

Comment: the title of your post makes no sense. ... most people will not even look at your post

Comment: Yeah.! You'r right about it. What do you think it will a god title for my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for here is to have a **modeless userform** which allows you to "continue to work elsewhere in the current application while the dialog box is displayed" ([More infos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263470%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

To to that, when you use the show method to make your form appear, you'll need to add the vbModeless option:

```
MainForm.Show(vbModeless)
```

Now, *how to keep the userform visible at all time* (on top of all windows)?
Assuming you are on Windows, you'll to make use of some API declarations. If you don't know exactly what this is, don't worry, you can just follow the following instructions:

**1) Copy the following code in a separate module**

```
Option Explicit

Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1

Public Enum HWND_TYPE
    HWND_TOP = 0
    HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
    HWND_TOPMOST = -1
    HWND_BOTTOM = 1
End Enum

#If VBA7 Then

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal hWndInsertAfter As LongPtr, _
        ByVal x As Long, _
        ByVal Y As Long, _
        ByVal cx As Long, _
        ByVal cy As Long, _
        ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

#Else

    Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
        ByVal X As Long, _
        ByVal Y As Long, _
        ByVal cx As Long, _
        ByVal cy As Long, _
        ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

    Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

#End If
```

**2) Copy this code for the AlwaysOnTop procedure in your userform code module:**

```
Private Sub AlwaysOnTop(caption As String)
'PURPOSE: This function allows the userform to remain on top of all windows - Adjusted
'REFERENCE: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/386643-userform-always-top-2.html

    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hWnd As Long
    #End If
    Dim lResult As Boolean

    If Val(Application.Version) >= 9 Then
        hWnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", caption)
    Else
        hWnd = FindWindow("ThunderXFrame", caption)
    End If

    If hWnd <> 0 Then

        lResult = SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE)

    Else

        MsgBox "AlwaysOnTop: userform with caption '" & caption & "' not found"

    End If

End Sub
```

**3) Use the AlwaysOnTop procedure somewhere in UserForm_Initialize. ie.:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Your code

    AlwaysOnTop Me.caption

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. your insight about the vbModeless Option it's very helpful. But I'm still struggling  in the part of my code where I would like the workbook I'm running the form from would be hide and any other workbook I could open from the form remains visible. Thank you

Comment: I just edited my answer to help you keep your form visible.

Comment: I followed your instructions in the steps 1,2 and 3 but I'm getting the error message: Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined. I'm sorry!

Comment: For step 2, it has to be in the **form** code module. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: It's is working Perfectly. I just have an Issue. The workbook1 the Userform1 is coming from is visible and I would like to keep it Hide while the rest of workbooks I open up from the from are visible. Do you know how could I just hide up the Workbook1 Thank you I really appreciate all the effort you put in you great code!

Comment: Try using something like `ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False`

Comment: @DecimalTurn, you need not distinguish between application versions (e.g. Excel < version97 or higher) when setting the window handle, simply use: `hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, caption)`.